# What program(s) can I use to automatically track a word count of my thesis

Tags: phd, thesis

I am a PhD student in mathematics, and I am just starting out writing my thesis. I would like a way to automatically keep track of the word count of my thesis, in such a way that I can plot and track my progress over time, but I have no idea how I would approach such a problem.

Ideally, the process of checking and storing the wordcount would happen automatically, and daily, and take only a little effort to set up.

Note: My thesis, like the vast majority of theses in mathematics, is being written using LaTeX, so any process would check either my .tex files, or the resulting .pdf

Comment: Mabe you should ask at http://tex.stackexchange.com. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document

Comment: Depending on your latex implementation there might be a word count package that you can use. Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171853/how-do-i-get-texcount-working-in-texniccenter

Comment: Note that my question is not just "How do I get a word count for a LaTeX document", but rather "What program(s) can I use to AUTOMATICALLY track a word count of my thesis?". Getting a word count for the thesis is only part of my question - I want a way of implementing it automatically on a daily basis so that I can monitor my word count daily as my thesis progresses.

Comment: First, write a script that counts the number of words in a LaTeX document. Secondly, schedule this script to run daily (using crontab, for example) and append its output to a log file.

Comment: First, your question is off-topic here. Second, there are many ways to achieve what you want. Third, counting words is a poor method of tracking progress.

Comment: I fail to see how it's off-topic. Based on the "What topics can I ask about here?" part of the Help section of this site, I would say this question could easily fit into the categories of "Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor", or "Inner workings of research departments". Furthermore, this is not a question which would help 'just me', but would is "a question that will help people like me", exactly as mentioned in the Help section of this website.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to academia. It probably best fits on [tex.se] since the word counting is the difficult part and automatising the rest is straightforward. Should you need an existing solution for this, this would be a question for [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @MarkB By that reasoning, literally anything that an academic does is on-topic. My life as a post-doc involves drinking coffee, for example. And I need get into work in the morning. One rule of thumb is that, if the exact same question could be asked by somebody outside academia, and receive the exact same answers, it probably isn't on-topic, here.

Comment: Well, MS Word can do it.. ;)

Comment: I agree with @101010111100 that counting words is a bad way to track progress.  It doesn't reflect the amount of work that goes into those words; some parts of your thesis will be much easier to write than others. And even if you cared only about the amount you've written, not its significance or the effort that went into it, you could get that "amount" information by counting pages rather than words --- and LaTeX gives me a page count every time I run it.

Comment: It's definitely not the only or best way to track progress, but I think that it is A way to measure progress, whatever its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You could track changes with git, and push your commits to GitHub at the end of each day. GitHub produces a nice graph, which also includes stuff that's edited out instead of only words added. A bit overkill for a word counter, but good practice more generally.